# oracle ELSE case runs regardless

Tags: oracle, case, negative-number

I have a case statement (myCol is a NUMBER):

`select case when myCol < 0 then 0 else round(POWER(10,AVG(LOG(10,myCol))),2) end myCol from myTable where id = 123 group by myCol;`

But Oracle seems to run the else clause regardless, and the POWER or LOG functions throw `ORA-01428: argument '-2.75' is out of range` when myCol is negative (-2.75). I would think the else clause would be ignored if myCol < 0 but maybe Oracle is compiling the entire statement before running?

I also tried using `decode(sign(myCol)...` but that also fails.

How can I handle this?

Comment: please show a complete, valid SQL statement, the table definition, and sample table data

Comment: The exact fragment you show can't be right - in one branch of the `case` expression you select `myCol` but in the other branch you select an expression based on aggregation (see the `AVG` function). That will never work. What is the TRUE query that gave you the error? It can't be the one you posted.

Comment: Please post a query that is complete enough that it can be ran.

Comment: Even better: don't post ANY code; instead, explain (without code!) the problem you are trying to solve. Perhaps your current code is not going in the right direction in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that query you posted isn't complete. Why? Because of this:

```
SQL> with test (mycol) as
  2    (select  2    from dual union all
  3     select -2.75 from dual
  4    )
  5  select case when myCol < 0 then 0
  6              else round(POWER(10,AVG(LOG(10,myCol))),2)
  7         end myCol
  8  from test;
select case when myCol < 0 then 0
                 *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function


SQL>
```

But, when you add the `group by` clause, you get error you mentioned:

```
SQL> with test (mycol) as
  2    (select  2    from dual union all
  3     select -2.75 from dual
  4    )
  5  select case when myCol < 0 then 0
  6              else round(POWER(10,AVG(LOG(10,myCol))),2)
  7         end myCol
  8  from test
  9  group by mycol;
            else round(POWER(10,AVG(LOG(10,myCol))),2)
                                           *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-01428: argument '-2.75' is out of range


SQL>
```

---

What to do? One option is to apply the `abs` function, because it is `GROUP BY` that causes your problems - it splits the whole result data set into rows, each `mycol` on its own, and that's where `-2.75` becomes *out of range*.

```
SQL> with test (mycol) as
  2    (select  2    from dual union all
  3     select -2.75 from dual
  4    )
  5  select mycol original_value,
  6         case when myCol < 0 then 0
  7              else round(POWER(10,AVG(LOG(10,abs(myCol)))),2)
  8         end myCol                           ---
  9  from test                               -- this
 10  group by mycol;

ORIGINAL_VALUE      MYCOL
-------------- ----------
         -2,75          0
             2          2

SQL>
```